# Display HTML Table Based on Dropdown List Selection

Tags: javascript, php, html, onchange

I have a dropdown list that is imported with data from a table in a database. Depending on what is selected, I want to display a certain table that shows the necessary information that correlates to what was selected in the dropdown list. How can I do this?

The table is only 2 columns, MR_ID (which is what is displayed in the dropdown list) and Supp_ID.

Here is my HTML/PHP that I have so far also followed by the little bit of JavaScript.

```
<!-- Dropdown List -->
    <select name="master_dropdown" id="mr_id" onChange="updatetable();">
    <option value="">Choose a MR_ID</option>
        <?php foreach($users->fetchAll() as $user): ?>
            <option data-name="<?php echo $user['MR_ID'];?>">
                <?php echo $user['MR_ID'];?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

<!-- Table -->
<p> 
    <div id="table_div">
        <table border="1" id="index_table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                <td>MR ID</td>
                <td>Supplier ID</td>
                <td>Edit</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="mr_id"><?php echo $user['MR_ID'];?></td>
                <?php foreach($users_one->fetchAll() as $supp); ?>
                <td class="supp_id"><?php echo $supp['Supp_ID'];?></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="edit" name="edit" value="Edit">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function updatetable() {
    var e = document.getElementById("mr_id");
    var itemSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex];

    document.getElementById("table_div").value = itemSelected.dataset.name;
}
```

Small sample size of what the table looks like:

[image]

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar Yes I am

Comment: why not you use the dropdown list using php itself without javascript function that you mentioned in the question

Comment: Well wouldnt I have to use javascript in some way? Wouldnt I need an onchange event so that it displays a different table each time corresponding to which selection I made in the dropdown?

Comment: ok dude.. could you send the snap of this table.. it used me to understand clearly in the design

Comment: I added a small sample size picture of what the table looks like